# How exactly scalability differs from load or performance testing?

Tags: testing, load, scalability

I hope this question will fit here. I have been doing a research regarding the aforementioned topic and cannot see the difference. Many sources simply put it that "scalability testing makes sure the software product will fit the efficiency requirements in the future as well as now". That sounds to me as a pure load testing with future expected load, where is the scalability part? I would expect some kind of extending (scaling) the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Scalabitity Testing** is differ from **Load Testing**.

**Scalability Testing:** Testing of the capability of the software product to be upgraded to accommodate increased loads.

Where as,

**Load Testing:** A type of performance testing conducted to evaluate the behavior of a
component or system with increasing load, e.g. numbers of parallel users and/or numbers
of transactions, to determine what load can be handled by the component or system.

Comment: I hope you got your answer. For more refer "Fundation of software testing" a book by 'Rex Black'.

Comment: If you got your answer then do not forget to accept it. For accep answer you have to click on right symbol under the answer.